# On the functors $\text{Hom}_R(k,-)$ and $k \otimes_R ( -)$ for Artinian local Gorenstein ring $R$

Tags: ct.category-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, cohen-macaulay-rings

Let $(R, \mathfrak m,k)$ be an Artinian local Gorenstein ring, hence $\text{Hom}_R(k, R)\cong k$, and so

$\text{Hom}_R(k, R^{\oplus n})\cong k^{\oplus n} \cong k \otimes_R R^{\oplus n} , \forall n \ge 0.$ Let $\mod (R) $ be the category of finitely generated $R$-modules, and $\mathcal F(R)$ be the subcategory of all finitely generated free $R$-modules.

Consider the two covariant functors $F, G: \mathcal F(R)\to \mod(R)$ defined as $F(-):=\text{Hom}_R(k,-)$ and $G(-):=k \otimes_R -$.  From what we have mentioned above, we see that $F(M)\cong G(M), \forall M \in \mathcal F(R) $.

My question is: Are the two functors $F$ and $G$ naturally Isomorphic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

We may as well take $\mathcal F(R)$ to be the category with objects $R^n$ for $n\in \mathbb N$ and take morphism $\operatorname{Hom}(R^m,R^n) =M_{n,m}(R) $.

Both functors take $R^n$ to $k^n$ and take a homomorphism in $M_{n,m}(R)$ to that matrix modulo the maximal ideal, so are naturally isomorphic.

Alternatively, we can express this functor as follows: Given $ a \in k \otimes_R M$, we map $b \in k$ to $M$ by taking $ab \in k \otimes_R M$ and applying the map $k \otimes_R M \to R \otimes_R M =M $ given as the tensor product of an injection $k\to R$ and the identity. This is an isomorphism for $R$, hence for all free modules.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your argument ... I know that $G(k) \cong \text{Hom}(Hom(k,-),G)$ where $\zeta \in G(k)=k\otimes k$ goes to the natural transformation defined as $Hom(k,M) \to G(M)=k\otimes M$ by sending $f \mapsto (id_k \otimes f)(\zeta)$ ... but could you please explain what are you doing now?

Comment: Here of-course when I write $G(k)$ I mean the corresponding extension of $G$ to whole of $\mod (R)$ instead of just $\mathcal F(R)$ ...

Comment: @user521337 I just want to calculate that natural transformation applied to the object $R$ and check it's not an isomorphism. The point being that if $id_k \otimes f (\zeta)$ were nonzero then $f: k \to R$ and the residue map $R \to k$ would compose to an isomorphism $k \to k$, which is impossible as then $R$ would split as a product module.

Comment: @WillSawin I think you might have missed that the OP defined $F$ and $G$ as functors on the category $\mathcal{F}(R)$ of finitely generated free modules, not on all finitely generated modules?

Comment: @JeremyRickard Indeed.

Comment: Thank you for your updated answer. Do you think the same would be true if I only had the Artinian hypothesis, but not the Gorenstein one? i.e. since $R$ is Artinian, so there exists integer $r>0$ such that $Hom(k, R)\cong k^{\oplus r}$. Then the functors $\mathcal F(R)\to \mod (R) $, $Hom(k, -)$ and $k^{\oplus r}\otimes (-)$ are still naturally Isomorphic?

Comment: @user521337 Yes, for the same reason involving matrices.